# sqlite version 2 with SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to use System.Data.SQLite to connect to a sqlite 2 file. I use SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder class to build the connection string but I couldn't set the version to 2 (exception). In the System.Data.SQLite document, it says the version is always 3.  So how can I connect to sqlite 2? Should I just use a string to build the connection string instead of using SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite 3 and SQLite 2 are not compatible.

You should convert the database into the SQLite 3 format.
This can be done with the `sqlite2` and `sqlite3` command-line tools:

```
sqlite2 olddb .dump | sqlite3 newdb
```

Comment: So is there a driver for sqlite2? I'm using .net btw.

Comment: There is no .net driver for SQLite 2.